# method is undefined for type and type of expression must be array

Tags: java

i am getting two weird errors here i dont know why ? basically what i am trying to do is create an array based on the number of spaces the user inputs and have them be consecutive numbers for example if the user inputs `3` the array will be the numbers `1, 2, 3`.

```
if (choice == 1){
    System.out.println("how big would you like your array?");
    choice = sc.nextInt();
    Array_1 userArray = new Array_1(choice);
    for (int i = 0; i < userArray.length; i++) {
        userArray[i] = i + 1;
    }
```

here is my Array_1 class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Array_1 {
    int[] internalarray;

    public Array_1(int x) {
        if(x>0) {
            this.internalarray = new int [x];
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Error: Array size must be non-negative");

        }

    }
    public static void printArray(int[] intarray) {
          for (int i = 0; i < intarray.length; i++) {
             if (i > 0) {
                System.out.print(", ");
             }
             System.out.print(intarray[i]);
          }
          System.out.println(" ");
       }
}
```

I realized i left out a line of code im having an error with by accident.  after that for loop i have one more line thats not working

```
Array_1.printArray(userArray);
```

Comment: you can indexing array by  userArray[i] but its object

Comment: not sure about `Array_1` class  but if u wanted to create an array then it will be `Array_1 userArray[] = new Array_1[choice];`

Comment: yeah i did that but that only allocates space, i want this for loop to fill this array with values depending on how many slots there are.  also do you need to see my array_1 class?

Comment: just edit the answer and provide the Array_1  implemenattion

Comment: ok i did that,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can access the array by using object of class

## quick fix

```
for (int i = 0; i < choice; i++) {
        userArray.internalarray[i] = i + 1;
    }
```

## suggegtion

make the instance variable as private make a method that will add the value in array

```
private int internalarray[];

public void add_data(int index, int val){
    this.internalarray[index] = val;
}
```

now call the  assign the value as like

```
if (choice == 1){
    System.out.println("how big would you like your array?");
    choice = sc.nextInt();
    Array_1 userArray = new Array_1(choice);
    for (int i = 0; i < choice; i++) {
        userArray.add_data(i,i+1);
    }
```

You might consider to exit if size less than zero

```
else {
            System.out.println("Error: Array size must be non-negative");
           System.exit(0);//exiting here
        }
```

Comment: ahh okay i see what i did wrong there but im still getting an error for array.length it says length cannot be resolved or is not a field

Answer (score 1):

Your self define class `Array_1` does not contain an attribute call `length`. Hence when you write the following, it causes an error:

```
userArray.length
```

`userArray` is not of type `int[]`. It is an object of type `Array_1` created by you.

If you.want to do that, write a getter in `Array_1` class to retrieve the internalArray:

```
class Array_1{
    public int[] getInternal() {
        return internalArray;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
userArray.getInternal().length
```